# I have two files receiving daily basis and I want to rename them like TRN_HIST_TBL.txt and TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI.txt

Tags: linux, mv

I have two files receiving daily basis as **TRN_HIST_TBL_16_AUG_2020** and **TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI_16_AUG_2020** and I want to rename them like **TRN_HIST_TBL.txt** and **TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI.txt**

I have written the rename command like below but it is creating only one file **TRN_HIST_TBL.txt**.

`mv TRN_HIST_TBL* TRN_HIST_TBL.txt`

`mv TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI* TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The first rename (mv) matches both files, so the second one overwrites the first one immediately.

Reversing the order won't help. That way, the file with the longer name would be renamed correctly, but then both it and the other file would be renamed again.

**Additional explanation and fix:**

Your inputs are `TRN_HIST_TBL_16_AUG_2020` and `TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI_16_AUG_2020`, and they are different every day, and you want the date part to not matter.

So when you write `mv TRN_HIST_TBL* TRN_HIST_TBL.txt`, the wildcard matches both files, and the command expands to:

```
mv TRN_HIST_TBL_16_AUG_2020 TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI_16_AUG_2020 TRN_HIST_TBL.txt
```

and that just names both the files to `TRN_HIST_TBL.txt`.

The second command fails because `TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI*` now does not match anything.

If you do the two commands in the other order, `TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI*` only matches one file, and you get

```
mv TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI_16_AUG_2020 TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI.txt
```

which is good, except that the other command **still** matches both names, and renames both files to `TRN_HIST_TBL.txt`

You need to hide one of the files while you rename the other one, and it needs to be the more distinctive name.

```
#.. Will only rename one file.
mv TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI* Hide_TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI.txt
#.. Wildcard will not match that file.
mv TRN_HIST_TBL* TRN_HIST_TBL.txt
#.. Set the final name.
mv Hide_TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI.txt TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI.txt
```

Comment: thanks... tried both the way...but no luck...

Comment: That's why I said "won't help". Posting more.

Comment: My preferred treatment would be to retain the original files (maybe clean them up weekly), and make soft links of the shorter preferred names. Probably also good to see if the supplier can use ISO date-stamps YYYY-mm-dd, and perhaps a less confusing naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

The glob that you are using for the first file matches both files. This causes the second file to overwrite the first file. Because of the way that the files are named, there's no way to avoid this with globbing. What you need to do instead is to use the entire filename:

```
mv TRN_HIST_TBL_16_AUG_2020 TRN_HIST_TBL.txt 

mv TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI_16_AUG_2020 TRN_HIST_TBL_NON_NPI.txt
```

Comment: Thanks... This will work for above file only... Everyday I am receiving the files with date change ... how to rename for the same....

Comment: @ShekhalalJadhav You would use the same method in my answer. `mv` with the entire existing filename to whatever you want the filename to be.

Comment: The automation seems to be a necessary part of the requirement.

Comment: The trick (as posted in my revised answer) is to use the distinctive **ending** of one of the filenames to add a distinctive **start** to that name, so the second glob is then unique.